# Recording while itunes song is playing

Tags: ios, io, audio

Our app records sound and plays it back on the earplugs in realtime.

Is it possible to move out of the app and play an iTunes track, while our app continues to record and playback what it receives on the mic?

To put things into perspective, our app records the user's breath, and plays it back real time. Is it possible to do this while listening to music from itunes?

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried to do this, but in theory it should work. Either [AudioToolbox](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html#section=Frameworks&topic=AudioToolbox) or [AVFoundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html#section=Frameworks&topic=AVFoundation) will be your best bet, maybe a mix of the two.